# how to move cursor to given positon when using shell

Tags: shell, terminal

I'm using iterm2 under MAC OSX.

I can using "Ctrl+a" move cursor to the head and using  "Ctrl+e" move cursor to the end

Is there any hotkey can move cursor to given position?

Comment: Specifically, you are using [tag:bash] in [tag:emacs] mode. The [tag:readline] keys are available to you, see http://linux.die.net/man/3/readline for more details.

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Ctrl-]</kbd><kbd>x</kbd> move to next `x`
<kbd>Alt-Ctrl-]</kbd><kbd>x</kbd> move to prev `x`

---

readline doc:

```
character-search (C-])
    A character is read and point is moved to the next occurrence of that character. A negative count searches for previous occurrences. 
character-search-backward (M-C-])
    A character is read and point is moved to the previous occurrence of that character. A negative count searches for subsequent occurrences.
```

Answer (score 2):

If you like Vi, then you can use it on the command line to do what you want (and much more!):

Add this line to your shell's rc file to turn it on (e.g., .bashrc):

`set -o vi          # Enable vi key bindings`

To activate that setting, `source .bashrc` (or open a new Terminal window).
Now whenever you want to go to a particular column position on the current line, type:

```
<Esc>0<col#>l
```

`Esc` enters vi command mode on the command line
`0` goes to the beginning of the line (column 0)
`#` is the position you want to go to
`l` (the letter el) means "move right" the previous number of characters